# How do I iterate clicks over a list of web elements in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to click on consecutive links in order to find the `company's domains` on a `Job Posting page`, with WebDriver using Python.

However, the `WebDriver` clicks on the first link only over and over again.

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://dribbble.com/jobs')
assert 'Dribbble' in driver.title
total_web = []
quotes = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("job-board-job-list"))
for quote in range(quotes): 
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('job-board-job-title').click()
        for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li/a"):
            website = a.get_attribute('href')

        new1 = ((website))
        total_web.append(new1)
        driver.back()

        quote+=1

df_web = pd.DataFrame(total_web,columns=['website'])
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is clicking 1st link because of this line.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('job-board-job-title').click()
```

This will always click the first element.

You need to use indexing.Try below code.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("job-board-job-list")
quotes = len(elements)
for quote in range(quotes):
    #Added this line to avoid stale which re-assigned the element again.
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("job-board-job-list")
    elements[quote].click()
```